# Poisson distribution within a period of time

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

On an average $20$ policyholders call on an info center of a life insurance company every hour. Find the probability that:

(A) Exactly $5$ policyholders will call within $10$ minutes.

(B) No policyholder will call within $10$ minutes.

(C) Less than $24$ policyholders will call.

Here is my attempt to solve the problem:

The average calls per $10$ˋ minutes is $20/6 = 3.33$

(A) $p(x=5) = 0.04979 * \displaystyle\frac{3.33^5}{5!} = 0.16989$

(B) $p(x=0) = 0.04979 * \displaystyle\frac{3.33^0}{0!} = 0.04979$

(C)

$p(x=0) = 0.04979 * \displaystyle\frac{20^0}{0!} = 0.04979$

$p(x=1) = 0.04979 * \displaystyle\frac{20^1}{1!} = 0.99580$

$0.04979 + 0.99580 = 1.04559 $

Please correct my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

For a) if the $ \lambda = 3.33  $  we have   $ \sim Pois(3.33)$

$$ f(5,3.33) = P(X=5) = \frac{3.33^{5}e^{-5}}{5!} \approx .02$$

For b)

$$ f(0,3.33) = P(X=0) = \frac{3.33^{0}e^{-3.33}}{0!} \approx .035 $$

For c)
If the number of callers per hour is $\lambda =20$ then we have $X \sim Pois(20)$

the pdf of the poisson distribution is given by

$$ f(k,\lambda) = Pr(X=k) = \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!} $$

then our pdf is

$$ f(k,20) = \frac{20^{k}e^{-20}}{k!}$$

the probability of getting fewer than 24 callers is given by the cdf.

$$ P(X \leq 23, 20) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k,20) = \sum_{k=0}^{23} \frac{20^{k}e^{-20}}{k!} $$

$$ P(X\leq 23, 20) = e^{-20} \sum_{k=0}^{23} \frac{20^{k}}{k!} \approx .78 $$

I am assuming you mean the less than 24 policy holders will call in an hour..if not you can switch it.